# How to get index of a for loop?

Tags: swift

In the following code, I would like to set a max text limit for each String in the array. However, I cannot use `ForEach` because that is reserved for Views. I would like to be able to grab the index value to accomplish something similar to the following.

```
    @Published var pollOptions : [String] = [""] {
        didSet {
            ForEach(0..<pollOptions.count, id: \.self) { i in
                if pollOptions[i].count > characterLimit && oldValue[i].count <= characterLimit {
                    pollOptions[i] = oldValue[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to use something like

```
for pollOption in pollOptions {
    // code to reset to old value if it exceed characterlimit
}
```

but I don't quite know how to get the index value to grab `oldValue[i]`

Comment: `for (index, pollOption) in pollOptions.enumerated() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.enumerated()` on collection to get an index per element:

```swift
var tmpArray = [
    "foo",
    "bar"
]

tmpArray
    .enumerated()
    .forEach { index, elemen in
        // do something
    }
```

Hope that helps.
On an unrelated not, be careful with property observers on properties with property wrappers especially `@Published`. You may introduce unwanted side effects.